# Enter the Loan amount and number of years. Display on the table the Interest, Monthly Payment and total payment

Tags: java

I am having issues with the code below, I have commented out what I am having issues with and the problem in detail but just in case here is the issue at hand. When I click on the Show Table Button, it does not display my calculations in the table, but if I add in a writeline("get working") at certain places in the If statements it works perfect. Im just not sure what I need to do in order to display the calculations on the table.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;


/* 
 * Developer: 
 * Date: 2/8/2016
 * Purpose:Enter the Loan amount and number of years. Display on the table the Interest, Monthly Payment and total payment.
 *          in the number of years from a text field, and it should display the 
 *          monthly and total payment
 */
public class Exercise17_13 extends JFrame {

    // add Panes, Panels and Labels 
    JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    TitledBorder titledBorder;
    JLabel jlblNumberYears = new JLabel("Number of Years");
    JLabel jlbLoanAmount = new JLabel("Loan Amount");
    JTextField jtfNumberYears = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField jtfLoanAmount = new JTextField(8);

    ButtonGroup btg = new ButtonGroup();
    JButton jbtShowTable = new JButton();

    public Exercise17_13() {

        //sets a Border around the program
        titledBorder = new TitledBorder("");
        this.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        jPanel1.setBorder(titledBorder);
        titledBorder.setTitle("");

        //add the actionListeners 
        jtfNumberYears.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtfNumberYears_actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
            //set the ShowTable button to receive ActionListener
        jbtShowTable.setText("Show Table");
        jbtShowTable.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jbtShowTable_actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
            //set LoanAmount to receive ActionListener
        jtfLoanAmount.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtfLoanAmount_actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
            //set each Panel to center using null
        add(jScrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(jta, null);
        add(jPanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jPanel1.add(jlbLoanAmount, null);
        jPanel1.add(jtfLoanAmount, null);
        jPanel1.add(jlblNumberYears, null);
        jPanel1.add(jtfNumberYears, null);
        jPanel1.add(jbtShowTable, null);
        btg.add(jbtShowTable);
    }
    //set the default frame of the program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise17_13 frame = new Exercise17_13();
        frame.setTitle("Exercise 17_13");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 250);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
        //sets LoanAmount to an editable action field
    void jtfLoanAmount_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jtfLoanAmount.setEditable(true);
    }
        //sets number of years to an editable action field
    void jtfNumberYears_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jtfNumberYears.setEditable(true);
    }
        //sets the show table button  action performed variables
    void jbtShowTable_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double number;
        double denomination;
        double x;
        double y;



        /* this part of the program is supposed to display the loanAmount and  loanYears calculation
         * but it currently does not display anything on the table. If I comment out the starting
         * if (jbtShowTable.isSelected()) then it displays the System.out.Println("working") just 
         * fine on the table but not the calculations. I am not sure where I went wrong with 
         * displaying the results on the table.
         */

        //this does calculations for the LoanAmount and Years and
        // if (jbtShowTable.isSelected()) {
        //System.out.println("working");
        if (e.getSource() == jtfLoanAmount) {
        double totalAmount = Double.parseDouble(jtfLoanAmount.getText().trim());
        jtfLoanAmount.setEditable(true);
        jtfNumberYears.setEditable(true);

            if (e.getSource() == jtfNumberYears) { //getSource returns the object on which the event initally occured
                double numOfYears = Double.parseDouble(jtfNumberYears.getText().trim());
                jtfLoanAmount.setEditable(false);
                jtfNumberYears.setEditable(false);
                for (double intRate = 5; intRate <= 8; intRate = Math.round((intRate + .125) * 1000.0) / 1000.0) {
                    number = intRate / 100.0 * totalAmount / 12;
                    x = -(12 * numOfYears);
                    y = (intRate / 100.0 / 12) + 1.0;
                    denomination = 1.0 - Math.pow(y, x);
                    jta.setText(new Double(intRate + " " + Math.round((number / denomination) * 100.0) / 100.0 + " "
                            + Math.round(((number / denomination) * 12 * numOfYears) * 100.0) / 100.0).toString());


                     }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are a couple of things wrong with it:

- What’s up with the `if (e.getSource() == ...)` statements? That method is only called when the button is pressed, there is no need to check the source of the event. And besides, you’re only executing The Real Magic when the source is two different things. At once.
- Then you are trying to parse a `Double` from a `String` containing three whitespace-separated numbers. What is that even trying to achieve?
- Then you are also overwriting your text area for every iteration of the “foo” loop. An `append` (with maybe a newline attached after each line) works better.
- As for the `jbtShowTable.isSelected`: I'm not sure why think this would be necessary as the method you’re in is called by the `ActionListener` registered with the button. If this method gets called somebody has had to push the button. :)

After I made these changes numbers started to appear in the “table.” If they are correct I don’t know but at least you can see them now. :)